# Why does it take me 40ms to select 1, but 500s to select 150?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I'm using SQLite 3. I have a table, `forums`, with 150 rows, and a table, `posts`, with ~4.4 million. Each post belongs to a forum.

I want to select the timestamp of latest post from each forum. If I ask for a single latest post, with `SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM posts WHERE forum_id = 5`, it takes me an average of 40 ms.

I ask for a list of all forums and their latest post with

```
SELECT forums.name, max(posts.timestamp)
FROM posts
JOIN forums ON posts.forum_id = forums.id
GROUP BY forums.name
```

It works, but it takes **500s** -- more than 12,000x as long, to select only 150x as much. If I just write a loop in my application to issue 150 individual select queries it is MUCH faster.

I did create an index on `posts.timestamp`, and a combined index of `posts.timestamp, posts.forum_id`. It didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do your indexes look like?

Comment: Why don't you group by `forum_id` directly?

Comment: My indexes are `CREATE INDEX forums_name ON posts (forum_id ASC)` and `CREATE INDEX time_and_forum ON posts (timestamp DESC, forum_id ASC)`.

Comment: You need to reverse the columns in the time_and_forum index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an index

```
create index ix_posts_forumid_timestamp on posts(forum_id, timestamp)
```

covering `GROUP BY posts.forum_id` query such as the following

```
select forum_id, max(timestamp) 
from posts
group by forum_id
```

If the query is processed within seconds (which should be), then you can test join with `forums`:

```
select f.name, t.maxTime
from forums f
(
  select forum_id, max(timestamp) maxTime
  from posts
  group by forum_id 
) t on t.forum_id = f.forum_id
```

Such a query can be covered by another index as well, but since you need all forums, I guess it is not as significant as the first index. And at the end, I believe that having the index the following query should be fast enough as well

```
select f.name, max(p.timestamp) maxTime
from posts p
join forums f on f.forum_id = p.forum_id
group by p.forum_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping on `forums.name` is probably the issue, since that column doesn't have an index. Try grouping on `posts.forum_id`.

If you're trying to get the forum name with the output, you could try the following:

```sql
SELECT forums.name, t.latestTimeStamp
From 
(select posts.forum_id, max(posts.timestamp) as latestTimeStamp
FROM posts
GROUP BY forums.forum_id) as t
JOIN forums ON t.forum_id = forums.id
```

Comment: It's been 7 minutes and this query is still running, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Does the sub-select alone run that long also?

Comment: The sub-select is running about 3 minutes so far and still going.